# Give an example of two subspaces $V_0\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ and $V_1\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $V_0\cup V_1$ is NOT a subspace in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am confused as how I would exactly prove that a union of two subspaces is not usually a subspace?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: You don't have to prove anything here. Just find an example. What are the subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Visually, a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ looks like a line, plane, or all of $\Bbb R^3$. The union of two lines looks like an $X$. That's not the same thing as the space spanned by those two lines, which would be the plane $X$ lies in.

Answer (score 1):

The sets $V_0=\{(k,0,0): k\in\Bbb R\}$ and $V_1=\{(0,k,0): k\in\Bbb R\}$ are subspaces. The vectors $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ are in $V_0\cup V_1$, but their sum $(1,1,0)$ is not.